# Using useEffect an Axios to get de datas in back. I'm trying to get 2 arrays of object to render

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, reactjs

i'm trying to get 2 arrays of object from my mysql db using Axios, but de console.log '3' is returning a empty array. Don't know whats wrong.

export default function Editar() {

```
let {clienteId} = useParams()

const [cliente, setCliente] = useState({})
const [vinculo, setVinculo] = useState([])

useEffect( ()   => {

    Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/getFromId/${clienteId}`).then((response) => {
        setCliente({
            clienteNome: response.data[1][0].clienteNome,
            clienteCpf: response.data[1][0].clienteCpf,
            clienteSexo: response.data[1][0].clienteSexo,
            clienteNascimento: response.data[1][0].clienteNascimento,
            
        })
        console.log(response.data, '1')
        console.log(response.data[[0]], '2')
        
        for (let i = 0; i <= response.data[[0]]; i++) {
            setVinculo({
                empresa: response.data[i].empresa,
                dataInicio: response.data[i].dataInicio,
                dataFim: response.data[i].dataFim,
                tipoAtividade: response.data[i].tipoAtividade,
            })
        }
        console.log(vinculo, '3')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

No its working good. state update is async call. so its take some delay to update. surely the delay higher than immediate `console.log`. you could use this data on your jsx instead of checking.

**[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
> update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
> delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
> does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

if you need to check

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(vinculo)
},[vinculo])
```